View only access to Package Spec, Body and Procedures
In Production Environment, we need to provide View only access to Package Spec, Package Body and Procedures. Any time we need to change the queries, we need to reach out to the admin to get the latest Package / Procedure.
Is there a way for us to get the view access without providing ability to execute the objects?
I have tried with synonym and execute option. But it give me ability to execute a procedure inside the package which we do not want.

If you only want to view the source code for the packages and procedures then store them in a source code repository and do not load them into the database.

What do you mean by "view only access"? Do you mean that you only want to see the source code of the package? Or do you mean that your packages have procedures in to SELECT some data and other procedures to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE data and you only want to be able to execute the procedures that SELECT and not the others?

Yes, simply have the DBA grant select any dictionary to the user(s) who need to view code. Then the grantee can query dba_source (+ dba_objects, dba_procedures, etc.) and see code without being able to execute it.

While technically this is correct, depending on the OP's working environment, this might not be possible in production. I know where I work it would be a complete non-starter, because select any dictionary exposes a lot more than just the specific source code the OP wants to see. Without granularity in the dictionary access, many systems would not allow this for developers. The suggestion above to place the code in a source control system and view it there is preferable by far from a security perspective.

Then grant SELECT on these three views.

@pmdba, I get it, but every company is different. In our env, there is little concern about dictionary access for developers. Source code is about the most sensitive thing it could give access to. Assuming nobody has hard-coded passwords, that is rarely if ever a problem. But if it is, then obviously a custom role could be defined to limit exactly which dictionary views could be read from.
